# ansible groups.variable in a tasks

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use a variable I have defined in a group_vars/file.yml and use it in a taks of my role like groups.my_variable (my_variable is the name of the group define in my inventory)

Here is my role tasks:

```
  ---

- name: "Create strusted storage pool"
  gluster_peer:
    state: "{{ CURRENT_NODES.state }}"
    nodes: "{{groups.group_name}}"
  tags: STORAGE_POOL
```

my inventory

```
[gluster]
glusterfs01
glusterfs02
ly-lab-elk
lpic
```

when I use it like this it works:

```
---
    
    - name: "Create strusted storage pool"
      gluster_peer:
        state: "{{ CURRENT_NODES.state }}"
        nodes: "{{ groups.gluster }}"
      tags: STORAGE_POOL
```

When I use groups.gluster directly in my tasks/pool_storage.yml as above I have expected result

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [glusterfs01] => {
    "groups.gluster": [
        "glusterfs01",
        "glusterfs02",
        "ly-lab-elk",
        "lpic"
    ]
}
ok: [glusterfs02] => {
    "groups.gluster": [
        "glusterfs01",
        "glusterfs02",
        "ly-lab-elk",
        "lpic"
    ]
}
ok: [ly-lab-elk] => {
    "groups.gluster": [
        "glusterfs01",
        "glusterfs02",
        "ly-lab-elk",
        "lpic"
    ]
}
ok: [lpic] => {
    "groups.gluster": [
        "glusterfs01",
        "glusterfs02",
        "ly-lab-elk",
        "lpic"
    ]
}
```

But when I use the variable set in group_vars/gluster.yml

```
group_names: gluster
```

in my tasks tasks/pool_storage.yml

```
nodes: "{{groups.group_name}}"
```

I have this result which is not good

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [glusterfs01] => {
    "group_names": [
        "gluster"
    ]
}
ok: [glusterfs02] => {
    "group_names": [
        "gluster"
    ]
}
ok: [ly-lab-elk] => {
    "group_names": [
        "gluster"
    ]
}
ok: [lpic] => {
    "group_names": [
        "gluster"
    ]
}
```

As I have different groups in my inventory file, I want to use a variable in which I will define my group name and then append it to groups.group_name or other way but to have the expected result.

Can someone help ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Group names and `group_vars` are interlinked by design. Defining `group_name: gluster` in the group_vars is the same as `groups.gluster`, I am not getting why you need to define a variable for this.

Comment: Because I have a role and that role will be used by different group defined in my inventory file.
TO avoid users to modify role, I prefer to use variable defined in a group_vars/group_name.yml.

Comment: Here is the difference:
TASK [debug] 
ok: [glusterfs01] => {
    "groups.gluster": [
        "glusterfs01",
        "glusterfs02",
        "ly-lab-elk",
        "lpic"
    ]
}
ok: [glusterfs02] => {
    "groups.gluster": [
        "glusterfs01",
        "glusterfs02",
        "ly-lab-elk",
        "lpic"
    ]
}
ok: [ly-lab-elk] => {
    "groups.gluster": [
        "glusterfs01",
        "glusterfs02",
        "ly-lab-elk",
        "lpic"

Comment: TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [glusterfs01] => {
    "group_names": [
        "gluster"
    ]
}
ok: [glusterfs02] => {
    "group_names": [
        "gluster"
    ]
}
ok: [ly-lab-elk] => {
    "group_names": [
        "gluster"
    ]

Comment: SO I want to use a variable and have the first result

Comment: Please edit your question and update these details (expected vs. actual outcome) its difficult to comprehend in comments.

Comment: I have updated my question, is it clear now plz ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to reference a `group_name` variable in `groups` you can try using the `groups[group_name]` syntax.

An example inventory:

```
[servers]
host-101.xxx.com
host-202.xxx.com

[group1]
g1-server1
g1-server2
```

A `group_vars/servers.yaml`:

```yaml
group_name: servers
```

A playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: servers
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: groups[group_name]
```

Gives the servers under `group1` defined as `group_name`:

```
ok: [host-101.xxx.com] => {
    "groups[group_name]": [
        "host-101.xxx.com",
        "host-202.xxx.com"
    ]
}
ok: [host-202.xxx.com] => {
    "groups[group_name]": [
        "host-101.xxx.com",
        "host-202.xxx.com"
    ]
}
```

One more thing to note is that you *don't need to establish the peers on each host of GlusterFS cluster*. So, either:

- target any 1 host of that group

or

- add `run_once: true` to the task

Example:

```yaml
- name: "Create strusted storage pool"
  gluster_peer:
    state: "{{ CURRENT_NODES.state }}"
    nodes: "{{ groups[group_name] }}"
  tags: STORAGE_POOL
  run_once: true
```

Comment: Thank you bro 
You saved my day

Yes you are write about running only once the peers etablishement.

Comment: Good to know it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Put the variable into the file *group_vars/gluster.yml* if you want the hosts of the group *gluster* to use it. The name of the file must be identical to the name of the group. This way Ansible will recognize to which groups the files in the directory *group_vars* belong.

If you can't change the name of *group_vars/file.yml* link it to *group_vars/gluster.yml*.

For example, given the simplified inventory for testing

```
shell> cat hosts
[gluster]
glusterfs01
glusterfs02
```

The group_vars

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/gluster.yml 
my_variable: foo
```

and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml 
- hosts: gluster
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: my_variable
```

give (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml

TASK [debug] *******************************************************
ok: [glusterfs01] => 
  my_variable: foo
ok: [glusterfs02] => 
  my_variable: foo
```

Comment: Thank you for  you answer but I have done already test all of your suggestion. What I want, is to declare the name of the group in a variable to use it then in the task. 

    `cat group_vars/gluster.yml 
    my_variable: gluster`
then in my task use it like this: 

     `- name: "Create strusted storage pool"  
       gluster_peer:
         state: "{{ CURRENT_NODES.state }}"     
         nodes: "{{groups.my_variable}}"
       tags: STORAGE_POOL`

Comment: See [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). [edit] the question and put your problem as [mre]. Delete the comments above, please.

Comment: Here is the difference:
 `TASK [debug] ok: [glusterfs01] => { "groups.gluster": [ "glusterfs01", "glusterfs02", "ly-lab-elk", "lpic" ] } ok: [glusterfs02] => { "groups.gluster": [ "glusterfs01", "glusterfs02", "ly-lab-elk", "lpic" ] } ok: [ly-lab-elk] => { "groups.gluster": [ "glusterfs01", "glusterfs02", "ly-lab-elk", "lpic"`

Comment: `TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************** ok: [glusterfs01] => { "group_names": [ "gluster" ] } ok: [glusterfs02] => { "group_names": [ "gluster" ] } ok: [ly-lab-elk] => { "group_names": [ "gluster" ]`

SO I want to use a variable in group_vars/gluster.yml and have the first result

Comment: @DiogèneMutombo Please actually read the comments and answers from the people trying to help you and **stop posting large portions of code and information needed to answer your question in comments**. Step back, relax, take time tho think this over and create a real [Minimal example](/help/mcve) that you will paste as an edit to your original question. I also suggest you spend some time reading other articles in the [help section](/help), sarting with [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask).